# Unable to create Asp.net HTTP app on a Windows 2008 RC2 Server with WebDAV using VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webdav, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create an ASP.Net website (File->New->Website->ASP.NET Web Site) in VS2010 with the Web location set to HTTP and the url set to a Windows Server 2008 R2 box.

When I try this I get an error that reads:

> Unable to create the Web site
>   'http://[MYSERVERNAME]/WebSite.'  The
>   Web server does not appear to have
>   FrontPage Server Extensions installed.

So, I went to find out how to install FPSE on Win 2k8 R2, and found out that it's no longer offered and to use WebDAV instead.  So, I loaded up WebDav on the 2k8 box and I'm still getting the error above.

Is there something I need to configure, etc to get this to work properly?

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Doing more research.  So far it looks like VS2010 just doesn't support WebDAV at all.  Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

You can map your drive to the web location once WebDav is configured:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis-7/

I then mapped a drive to the http location as shown in the tutorial.

Next I created a new site in VS2010 and for location i used my mapped drive. VS is now hung up but its creating the directory structure for a website over WebDAV however its taking very long to do so!!! Not sure if this is my network/setup that i have here at home. Testing this out for the first time.

Edit:
I learned later that you Visual Studio does not support WebDav. The way you'd want to use it is to create the site locally in VS and then publish it to the mapped drive as instructed in the tutorial (the drive that's mapped to an HTTP://... location). Working on the site directly via the UNC path with Visual Studio will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Tad: Run the Web Platform Installer on your machine and see if it offers FPSE.

Comment: I'm unable to find it.  It doesn't show up by default and nothing I've tried searching makes it show up.